# Graphql error when building react-native app

Tags: react-native, graphql, apollo

I'm getting this error on node when I try and `npm run android` my react native app

> Unable to resolve "./printError" from
>   "node_modules/graphql/error/index.js

The error only occurs when attempting to import any libraries that require Graphql. Graphql is installed, and I've uninstalled and reinstalled my node_modules several times attempting to fix this but nothing works. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: is there a file at path `node_modules/graphql/error/printError.js` ?

Answer (score 0):

`printError` was added with [v0.12.0](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/releases/tag/v0.12.0). Apollo requires at least v14.5.4. You can install the latest version with `npm install graphql@latest`.